# Bootstrap Carousel going 1 too many slides at the very end

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So here is my jquery and my html code, I have content in those li's but I didnt want to blow up the page with all the content. Was just hoping it was somewhere in the jquery that I wasnt seeing. Thanks

$(function () {
            $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
                wrap: 'both',
                auto: '4'
                // Core configuration goes here
            });

```
        $('.jcarousel-pagination')
    .on('jcarouselpagination:active', 'a', function () {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
    .on('jcarouselpagination:inactive', 'a', function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    .on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    })
    .jcarouselPagination({
        perPage: 1,
        item: function (page) {
            return '<a  href="#' + page + '">' + page + '</a>';
        }
    });
        $('.carousel-control.left').jcarouselControl({
            target: '-=1'
        });

        $('.carousel-control.right').jcarouselControl({
            target: '+=1'
        });

        $('.carousel-control, .jcarousel-pagination').click(function () {
            $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll('stop');
        });

    });
    $(function () {
        $('#first.jcarousel')
    .jcarousel({})
    .jcarouselAutoscroll({
        interval: 10000,
        target: '+=1',
        autostart: true
    });
    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#carouselcontain').click(function () {
           interval: false;
    });

<div id="ContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_carouselcontain" class="carouselcontain">
        <div id="first" class="jcarousel" data-jcarousel="true"> 
            <ul class="carousel-images">
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jcarousel-pagination" data-jcarouselpagination="true"></div>
        </div>
          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselcontain" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-left" ></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselcontain" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: Or I should say after slide 5 it doesnt go back to 1 automatically

Comment: what does it do after 5? does it just sit there?

Comment: No it looks like it moves about 10 pixels to the right like that is another slide sits there for the time allowed then goes to number 1 slide

Comment: do you give the li an explicit height and width in your css?

Comment: yes just a width, but now looking it has a width and a max -width, but both are set to 590px